# Is it possible to import the data from Oracle Database 7 to Oracle Database 11g?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, zend-framework, oracle11g

I am new to oracle and my client's data are stored in Oracle Database 7, based on my research Oracle Database 7 is not available to download *(you need to contact oracle for this version)* also if you want to connect it to PHP you need PHP version that are less than 5.0 and since I'm going to work on my local machine, I prefer to use some free version of Oracle that's why I'm planning to use Oracle Database 11g. The requirements are to generate reports based on their existing and for future data using Zend Framework.

My current options are :

1. Export the data from Oracle Database 7 as CSV and import it on MySQL using PHP.
2. Export the data from Oracle Database 7 and import in on Oracle Database 11g.

Questions :

1. Is it possible to import the data from Oracle Database 7 to Oracle Database 11g?
2. If question 1 is yes, then is there any tool on Oracle Database 7 that can perform Daily Scheduled task to export the data as CSV or any backup file? If yes, is there any tool in Oracle Database 11g that can perform Daily Scheduled task to import data from CSV or any backup file from Oracle Database 7?
3. Is there anyone here tried & encountered this scenario? Any options or idea on how to do this?

Every comments and suggestions are welcome and very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, someone still has a system running V7???  How many tables are we talking about here?  You could export to csv, and import into new oracle using external tables or SQLLoader.

Comment: yeah, I'm also surprised when I heard that Oracle V7. Anyway, thanks to your quick answer. 50+ tables including the reference tables. I will try your suggestions when I receive the sample data from my client. Thanks man.

Comment: If your clients had licensed software then Oracle could provide them with the version 7 package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

11g should be able to import a dumpfile generated from version 7.  I have not tried this, but Oracle claims that the [11g imp utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1023560) can work with Oracle versions that are 28 years old!

See support document 132904.1 for all the details.  It claims that "Import can read export dump files created by Export release 5.1.22 and higher (up to same version)."  And it even includes an example of exporting from 7.3.4 into 11.1.0.

Run the version 7 [`exp`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm) program to create a dump file, and use the 11g `imp` program to import the data.  For 11g, the `imp` and `exp` utilities are included with the default install and can be called from the command line.  I assume your version 7 install has an `exp` program somewhere.  Those utilities can be scheduled with the relevant operating system utilities.

Comment: Thanks to your quick response @jonearles . will try this option after I receive the sample dump file from my client. I will accept your answer if this will work. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Q1) YES.

Q2) Oracle v11.2 has a very powerfull scheduler on board. Complete with Remote Job Agents that you can install on a different - licensed - server than the controlling database. You can make your jobs do anything script.

Q3) Similar scenarios.

Other options are have a v8 database use it as an intermediate server to be able to connect the databases using database links. The v7 - v8 - v10 - v11 can all communicate. Not 100% sure about v7 and higher than v8. That is all historic stuff.

Easiest is to upgrade the v7 to v11. There will come a time that the hardware that runs on the v7 server stops working. That the new server does not support the correct OS version required for v7. In that case: problems ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your great options @ik_zelf. I will give you feedback after I try this possible options. Thanks again.